How to use `distinct()` in a query in Cakephp5?
I'm looking for the way to avoid duplicates in a query in Cakephp5.
Here is my table rubriques :
id | ... | model | ...
======================
1  | ... | CustomRubriques | ...
2  | ... | CustomRubriques | ...
3  | ... | CustomRubriques | ...
4  | ... | CustomRubriques | ...

Here is my query :
$rubriquesModels = $this->Rubriques
                            ->find()
                            ->select('model')
                            ->distinct()
                            ->all()
                            ->extract('model');

debug($rubriquesModels->toArray());

Here is the result of the query :
 (int) 0 => 'CustomRubriques',
 (int) 1 => 'CustomRubriques',
 (int) 2 => 'CustomRubriques',
 (int) 3 => 'CustomRubriques',

Why doesn't distinct() remove the duplicates ?
--EDIT--
It seems the problem comes from my RubriquesTable where I do :
// in RubriquesTable.php
 public function beforeFind(Event $event, SelectQuery $query, ArrayObject $options, $primary)
    {
       $query
            ->enableAutoFields()
            ->find('translations');
            
       return $query;
    }

When I remove this callback, my query with “distinct” works well.
Don't know why does the code of my callback beforeFind() make my query ->distinct() not working... (?)

The parameters to distinct() are optional, but I've always used it like ->distinct('model').

@GregSchmidt it returns a "Database Error" when I do ->distinct('model')...

Surely there are more specifics about that error than just "Database Error"?

@GregSchmidt  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'cms-infoliv5.Rubriques.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Seems Cake is using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT to implement this, and it's doing it in a way that wants the id to be in the selected fields. You might try ->select(['id', 'model']) to see if that resolves it; you're throwing away everything else with the extract call anyway, and id is a very small extra bit of data to pull across.

change ->distinct() to ->distinct(['Rubriques.model'])

thanks but the problem is not coming from here. I've edited my question.

maybe it will left join to i18n table too.
